# InvalidArgumentError: computed output size would be negative

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am creating a small CNN for 2-class text classification.  I was able to create and run (successfully) the CNN with a single convolution layer, but when I try adding a second, I get an error that I cannot resolve.  The error is on the output from the second conv.

The NN compiles and starts to fit but then fails with an error.

I have tried removing the first conv and maxpool layers, and everything worked.

Suggestions on what to do would be appreciated.

```py
kerCNN2 = keras.Sequential()
kerCNN2.add(keras.layers.Embedding(len(dictChck), 32))
kerCNN2.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(24,5,activation=tf.nn.relu))
kerCNN2.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(5))
kerCNN2.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(16,5,activation=tf.nn.relu))
kerCNN2.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
kerCNN2.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu))
kerCNN2.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
kerCNN2.summary()

kerCNN2.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])

trainHistCNN2 = kerCNN2.fit(encTrain, trainYPartial, epochs = 1, batch_size = 128, validation_data=(encTrainEval, trainYEval), verbose=1)
```

The results of compilation:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_23 (Embedding)     (None, None, 32)          76915776  
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_32 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 24)          3864      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_13 (MaxPooling (None, None, 24)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_33 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 16)          1936      
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_3 ( (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_31 (Dense)             (None, 16)                272       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 76,921,865
Trainable params: 76,921,865
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The (relevant portion of) error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): computed output size would be negative
     [[Node: conv1d_33/convolution/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](conv1d_33/convolution/ExpandDims, conv1d_33/convolution/ExpandDims_1)]]
```

Comment: what are the shapes of `encTrain` and `trainYPratial`?

Comment: encTrain is (3423300,10) and trainYPartial is a list with 3423300 elements

Comment: `trainYPartial = np.array(trainYPartial)` ?

Comment: did not help.  again, as I said, changing NOTHING but removing one of the 2 conv + pooling layers works.  Just when I add the second conv layer it does not

Answer (score 3):

That's because your Tensor shape is less then the size of conv kernel.

> e.g. Tensor shape is (None, None, 10, None), but the filter of conv is (X, 16, X, X).

10 is less then 16.